# The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an App using Firebase as the backend. Initially the code was working alright but after updates from firebase, I am having an issue. The issue is: **The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'**. Within the excerpt of the code below, I have added ** to indicate where the issue is. Any help is welcome.

```
@override
  initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .currentUser
        .**then**((currentUser) => {
      if (currentUser == null)
        {Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login")}
      else
        {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("voters")
              .doc(currentUser.uid)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot result) =>
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomePage(
                      ))))
              .catchError((err) => print(err))
        }
    })
        .catchError((err) => print(err));
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the current user is no longer a future. You likely increased the version of your packages in `pubspec.yaml` without modifying your code to reflect the breaking changes.

Retrieving the user is now done synchronously.
Retrieve the user as you would with synchronous code and pass it where it's needed.

```dart
@override
  initState() {
    User currentUser= FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (currentUser == null)
        {Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login")}
      else
        {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("voters")
              .doc(currentUser.uid)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot result) =>
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomePage(
                      ))))
              .catchError((err) => print(err))
        }
    super.initState();
  }
```

If you still need to catch an error, wrap the relevant code in `try-catch`.